# AppendTo duplicates content by resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code:

```
function adaptMenu() {

    /*  toggle menu on resize */
    var screenWidth = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;

    if (screenWidth < 768) { $("#menusx li").appendTo("#menu ul"); }
    else if (screenWidth >= 768) { $("#menu li.subLi").appendTo("#menusx ul"); }
}

$(document).ready(adaptMenu);
$(window).resize(function() {
    adaptMenu();
});
```

It should move some "li" elements from one menu to the main menu on smartphones. Everything works properly when the page loads and by shrinking the viewport.
The problem is by enlarging the window, the code duplicates the content.

Please help:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method for this:

```
$("#menusx li").detach().appendTo("#menu ul");
```

This will remove your `li` elements from DOM before appending it again.

Comment: I already try this method. Duplicate content appears in the submenu and not where it is removed, and just by enlarging the window.

Comment: Can you show your HTML? jsfiddle example would be great also

Comment: Sorry I saw now that is a problem due to the rest of the javascript code that I have not published before. Here the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gnpmq904/1/